# Setting font facename for emacs and xterm under linux

Tags: faces, fonts

How can I set the font name and size for Arabic letters in both emacs and xterm? Thanks

Comment: What  have you attempted?

Answer (score 1):

The following will set the default fonts in your GUI Emacs and XTerm to "DejaVu Sans Mono" which is fairly common and has nice looking Latin and Arabic glyphs.

For your XTerm, and using `uxterm` a wrapper around `xterm`, add the following to the end of your `~/.Xresources`:

```
UXTerm*faceName: xft:DejaVu Sans Mono:size=10
```

Then run `xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources`. This will take the changes you just made to your `~/.Xresources` file and apply them to your current session. Subsequent `uxterm`s you start will use these changes.

For Emacs edit your `~/.emacs.d/init.el` and add:

```
 (set-default-font "DejaVu Sans Mono:size=10")
```

Restart Emacs for this to take effect.

Obviously replace my example font with something you like. My example considers using only one font, but both font systems have a “fall through” system where you can use different fonts for different languages. Read up on XTerm’s and Emacs docs for specifics about that.

Comment: I have `xterm`; so I used `XTerm.vt100.faceName: DejaVu Sans Mono:size=10:antialias=false` along with `(set-default-font "DejaVu Sans Mono")` . It works fine, except that the Arabic letters in the terminal are reversed (LTR). Should I use `UXterm`? I did not find it for Archlinux, which is my distro.

Comment: I found `uxterm` on my system; I used your settings. Same problem (LTR letters) exist.

Comment: I don't think there's any RTL or bidirectional support in standard (unicode) `xterm`. For `urxvt` there's a [plugin-in](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Rxvt-unicode/Tips_and_tricks#Bidirectional_support). I've never used it, but [`mlterm`](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mlterm/) is supposed to have the best RTL/bidirectional support in a terminal emulator. Every modern Linux distro should package it, including Arch via the AUR.